# R: change value in a dataframe without losing factor levels

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to set one value in a dataframe, without losing the levels.  Just setting the value seems to reduce levels to 1.   Initally:

```
str(one_row_df$city)
Factor w/ 297 levels "san francisco","atlanta",..: 186
```

Settings:

```
one_row_df$city <- as.factor("new york")
str(one_row_df$city)
Factor w/ 1 level "new york": 1
```

How do I set this field without losing all the factor levels?

Comment: are you trying to rename a level in your factor?

Comment: just creating a single observation with the same structure as the df so I can run a prediction on it (xgboost)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use  `factor` instead of `as.factor`:

```
one_row_df$city <- factor("new york", levels=c(levels(one_row_df$city), "new york"))
```

Comment: perfect!  what should i do for NAs?